# Is there a performance trick to avoid implicit pickling?

Tags: python, json, python-multiprocessing

I have a code pipeline with three different ends. A service outputs JSON data, another decode it, reads a part of it, then dispatch it to an other process which is reading a [multiprocess Pipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe). The catch is, the writing process might output a lot of data, and from what I've understood Pipe implicitly pickle objects [which is not a good thing for performance](http://www.benfrederickson.com/dont-pickle-your-data/). I can send the raw JSON through the Pipe via send_bytes and decode it a second time which might offer slightly better performance but it seems as much a waste to double-decode the data.

Can I use a performance trick to decode my data only once, and still get an intermediate result in my dispatching process ? I only need one value from the JSON object, and have full control over the whole pipeline.

Sorry for not providing a code sample, things aren't ready yet

Comment: Maybe in your case forking() dispatcher process after data has been decoded will be faster than decoding the data again?

Comment: I can't really, the data can be sent way after the process is spawned. The closest thing to my mind that represent what I want to do is a router which would need to route an IP packet without reading the body. I may need to go away from a monolithic JSON object and implement a header of some sort